# Move octopress blog to subfolder

Tags: octopress, digital-ocean

I have currently my octopress blog up and running on my digital ocean droplet and everything works fine. But it is in the root folder of the droplet and I want to move it to a `blog` folder. Is that just moving all content to that subfolder, or is there more work to do to get this done to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Octopress documentation, if you are deploying in a subdirectory you'll need to update the following files:

- _config.yml
- config.rb
- Rakefile

> If you're deploying to a subdirectory on your site, or if you're using
>   Github's project pages, make sure you set up your urls correctly in
>   your configs. You can do this almost automatically:
>
> ```
> rake set_root_dir[your/path]
>
> # To go back to publishing to the document root
> rake set_root_dir[/] Then update your _config.yml and Rakefile as follows:
>
> # _config.yml
> url: http://yoursite.com/your/path
>
> # Rakefile (if deploying with rsync)
> document_root = "~/yoursite.com/your/path"
> ```
>
> To manually configure deployment to a subdirectory, you'll change _config.yml, > config.rb and Rakefile. Here's an example for deploying a site to the /awesome
>   subdirectory:
>
> ```
> # _config.yml
> destination: public/awesome
> url: http://example.com/awesome
> subscribe_rss: /awesome/atom.xml
> root: /awesome
>
> # config.rb - for Compass & Sass
> http_path = "/awesome"
> http_images_path = "/awesome/images"
> http_fonts_path = "/awesome/fonts"
> css_dir = "public/awesome/stylesheets"
>
> # Rakefile
> public_dir = "public/awesome"
> # If deploying with rsync, update your Rakefile path
> document_root = "~/yoursite.com/awesome"
> ```

source: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/